# ErrorException Undefined variable: posts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to get some field data in database in several different tables  and i have made relationship between tables in post model , and in ListingPageController i have assigned post model and created variable named $posts to use it in list.blade.php page while i am trying to use it will give me this error please help

**Following code is ListingPageController page:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class ListingPageController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('front.listing');
    }

    public function listing($id){ 

         $posts = Post::with(['comments','category','creator'])
                      ->where('status',1)
                      ->where('category_id',$id)
                      ->orWhere('created_by',$id)
                      ->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(3); 

       return view('front.listing',compact('posts'));
  }


}
```

**Below code is listing.blade.php page**

```
@foreach($posts as $key=>$post)
                @if($key === 0)

<div class="entity_wrapper">
    <div class="entity_title header_purple">
        <h1><a href="{{ url('/category') }}/{{ $post->category_id }}">{{ $post->category->name }}</a></h1>
    </div>
    <!-- entity_title -->

    <div class="entity_thumb">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('post') }}/{{ $post->main_image }} " alt="{{ $post->title }}">
    </div>
    <!-- entity_thumb -->

    <div class="entity_title">
        <a href="{{ url('/details') }}/{{ $post->slug }}" target="_blank"><h3> {{ $post->title }} </h3></a>
    </div>
    <!-- entity_title -->

    <div class="entity_meta">
        <a href="#">{{ date('F j- Y',strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</a> , by: <a href="{{ url('/author') }}/{{ $post->creator->id }}">{{ $post->creator->name }} </a>
    </div>
    <!-- entity_meta -->

    <div class="entity_content">
        {{ str_limit( $post->short_description,200,'...' )  }}
    </div>
    <!-- entity_content -->

    <div class="entity_social">

        <span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>{{ count($post->comments) }} <a href="#"> Comments</a></span>
    </div>
    <!-- entity_social -->

</div>
<!-- entity_wrapper -->
      @else
    @if($key === 1)
<div class="row">
    @endif <!-- first if will be ended here -->
    <div class="col-md-6" style="min-height: 555px;margin-bottom:2%">
        <div class="category_article_body">
            <div class="top_article_img">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('post') }}/{{ $post->list_image }}" alt="{{ $post->title }}">
            </div>
            <!-- top_article_img -->

            <div class="category_article_title">
                <h5>
                    <a href="{{ url('/details') }}/{{ $post->slug }}" target="_blank"> {{ $post->title }} </a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <!-- category_article_title -->

            <div class="article_date">
                <a href="#">{{ date('F j- Y',strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</a> , by: <a href="{{ url('/author') }}/{{ $post->creator->id }}">{{ $post->creator->name }}</a>
            </div>
            <!-- article_date -->

            <div class="category_article_content">
               {{ str_limit( $post->short_description,100,'...' )  }}
            </div>
            <!-- category_article_content -->

            <div class="article_social">

                <span><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>{{ count($post->comments) }} <a href="#"> Comments</a></span>
            </div>
            <!-- article_social -->

         </div>
        <!-- category_article_body -->

        </div>
    <!-- col-md-6 -->
    @if($loop->last)

    </div>
      @endif
        @endif
         @endforeach
```

Comment: The controller uses `front.listing` file, but you show us `list.blade.php`, which is not the same file.

Comment: sorry i have wrong written the page is already named listing

Comment: Which file/line is the error? If it's a view, you can get the parsed code in `storage/framework/views`

Comment: u can replace ```->where('status',1)->where('category_id',$id)``` with ```->where(['status' => 1, 'category_id' => $id])->...```

Comment: @ledisoft it will give same error

Comment: @FelippeDuarte The error is "  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\news\resources\views\front\listing.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Undefined variable: posts (0) "

Comment: @Muhamad Sorry, my comment was not a solution to your problem, it was a micro-optimization to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index function doesn't have a `posts` variable defined. You need to update your view or pass an empty variable posts:

```
public function index(){
    return view('front.listing', ['posts'=>[]]);
}
```

Or in your view:

```
@if(isset($posts))
    @foreach($posts as $key=>$post)
    ...
@endif
```

Or create a new view, change the logic, etc, it's up to you.

Comment: I prefer to pass an empty variable for posts . Thank You

Answer (score -1):

Can you try it like that to see what it tells you?

```
return view('front.listing', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

***EDIT1***

Verify that the content you are passing to `listing.blade.php` is correct .. on the first line of `listing.blade.php` type `{{ dd($posts) }}`

and check what result you are getting.